# Get body of request in ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2

I faced problem like this.

I have method in controller, that receive data in body of POST request.

Here is method.

```
 // POST: api/StartWorkingDays
    [ResponseType(typeof(StartWorkingDay))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostStartWorkingDay(StartWorkingDay startWorkingDay)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.StartWorkingDays.Add(startWorkingDay);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(new { Result = "Success", Message = "Saved Successfully"});
        //return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = startWorkingDay.Id }, startWorkingDay);
    }
```

How I can see body of request that I receive?

Thank's for help.

Comment: startWorkingDay should be the body of your request and also check Request.Content

Comment: Okay, so I can see what mobile app sends me in `startWorkingDay`?@Sujith

Comment: Yes. When you debug the code you can see the startWorkingDay filled with the content that you have posted to it. If the data that you are posting is not same as StartWorkingDay model, then startWorkingDay would be null. In that case you can read Request.Content and see what has been posted to.

Comment: Thank's I will try.@Sujith

Comment: Okay, it works. But I have another question if API is on Azure and mobile application is sending requests on www.******.com

How I can read body of request?@Sujith

Comment: Hm. for example I can do it like this `return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = startWorkingDay.Id }, startWorkingDay);`

@Sujith

Answer (score 1):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostStartWorkingDay([FromBody] StartWorkingDay startWorkingDay) 
    {
      //here above startWorkingDay is body your mobile developer will send 
       //you and data can be viewed while debugging ,
       //tell mobile developer to set content-type header should be JSON. 
       return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, "Success");
    }
```

Why your return type is Json ? you should use HttpResponse . I believe you are using Web api 2 . With Attribute routing and if you want to send response in json format then remove Xml formatter from WebApiConfig.cs file inside App_Start folder